# Nuxt i18n resets data object on language switch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I've been integrating [nuxt-i18n](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n) into one of my projects to enable multiple languages. It all works fine, but when I switch language while filling in a form, all data from the page is lost.

So, I created a form and use `v-model` to bind the data to the page's data object.

```js
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">{{ $t('form.username') }}</label>
   <input v-model="user.username" type="username" class="form-control" id="username" />
</div>
```

This is the page's data object

```js
data: () => {
  return {
     user: {
       username: ''
    }
}
```

So when I type a username in the field, the model is updated, as I expect. But as soon as I switch the language from that page, the data is lost as soon as the chosen language has been set.

This is how I switch the language when clicking, for example, the dutch flag icon.

```js
switchLocalePath(locale.code) // local.code is 'nl' in this case
```

When the user switches the language, the slug should also update. The code below shows the settings for the `i18n` package in my `nuxt.config.js` file.

```js
modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: [
        {
          code: 'en',
          iso: 'en-US',
          name: 'English'
        },
        {
          code: 'nl',
          iso: 'nl-NL',
          name: 'Nederlands'
        }
      ],
      defaultLocale: 'nl',
      parsePages: false,
      pages: {
        'account/register': {
            en: '/account/register',
            nl: '/account/registreren'
        },
        'account/index': {
            en: '/account/login',
            nl: '/account/inloggen'
        }
      },
      vueI18n: {
        fallbackLocale: 'nl',
        messages: { nl, en }
      }
    }],
]
```

**The actual question**

So almost everything works just as I expect. But every time I change the language, the page's data object is cleared (It doesn't seem like the page actually reloads). So when filling in a form, then changing the language before submitting, all data is lost.

How can I make sure, if possible, that all data presists when toggling the language?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to change the locale and the same behavior occurs.

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-item
        v-for="locale in availableLocales"
        :key="locale.code"
        @click="$router.push(switchLocalePath(locale.code))"
    >
        <v-list-item-title>{{ locale.name }}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Also tried using `$i18n.setLocale(locale.code)` same thing happens.

Not sure if this should be a comment but since I can't comment yet (requires 50 rep), I post this as an extension of the description of the problem.